# Hide elements from humans, but not bots

Tags: javascript, css

I am using [Qualtrics survey software](https://qualtrics.com) and experiencing issues with bots. Their own bot detection tools are not sufficient.

I want to detect if a bot is completing the form. To do so, I thought I would change the colors of one field to be all white (same color as the background). The following CSS is *not* working to do so:

```
#ID > * {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: white ! important;
}
```

The following JavaScript is also not working:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('ID').childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    if(nodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div'){
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white !important';
        nodes[i].style.color = 'white !important';
    }
}
```

How do I target an element and all its child elements and make them invisible to the human eye, but not a computer?

**MWE on Qualtrics**

https://uwartsandsciences.sjc1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_5sYhuvDNJcRpdS6

The first question (ID == `QID1`) I want hidden from the human eye. The second can remain visible.

Comment: `I want to detect if a bot is completing the form. To do so, I thought I would change the colors of one field to be all white (same color as the background)` -- Just out of curiosity, what exactly is the purpose of serving white background & text input field to a bot?

Comment: @AndrewL64, a human would not see this input and would skip it. A bot would see this input, however, and select a response.

Comment: @David perhaps it has to do with Qualtrics itself. Here's a MWE to play with: https://uwartsandsciences.sjc1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_5sYhuvDNJcRpdS6

#QID1 and it's children I want to hide.

Comment: Why not just use `visibility: hidden;`, a simple JS math challenge or a captcha instead?

Comment: You probably meant `#ID * { background-color: white !important; color: white ! important; }` When you add the `>`, that makes it apply to only the immediate children.

Comment: hidefrom('humans');hidefrom(!'bots')

Answer (score 1):

```
display: none;
```

have that on the input field you want hidden if what you are trying to do is set up a honeypot.

Humans will not see it but the bots will see it as they are reading the html.

[Honeypot implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861325/honeypot-implementation)